# How to filter the Array of Dictionary if the dictionary elements are null?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I need to filter the array of dictionary , but in my structure some of the values are `null`

```
 "data": [
        {
            "date": "2019-04-12 00:00:00",
            "points": 825,
            "trips": [
                {
                    "id": 108,
                     "trip_detail": “<null>”
    }
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-04-11 00:00:00",
            "points": 2475,
            "trips": [
                {
                    "id": 73,
                     "trip_detail": {
                        "id": 53,
                        "score": 8.25,
                        "points": 825,
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 74,
                       "trip_detail": {
                        "id": 54,
                        "score": 8.25,
                        "points": 825,
                    }
                },
```

so in the above result I need to remove the first array of dictionary as well as that array.

Comment: `1 ->` **remove the first array of dictionary as well as that array** pls specify which  array you talking abt? `2 ->` **need to filter the array of dictionary** according to which key you wanted to filter your data ?

Comment: if the `trips` object null I need to remove the hole object 
{
            "date": "2019-04-12 00:00:00",
            "points": 825,
            "trips": [
                {
                    "id": 108,
                     "trip_detail": “<null>”
    }

Comment: That's seems to be JSON. First serialize it. Then we'll see. Did you attempt anything? Also you want to filter, or skip them when parsing?

Comment: I have used the following Predicate , now its fine
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"trip_detail != null"]];

Comment: @Nandhakumar You need to show your code in your question. [Edit] the question and add (as text) your relevant code. Clearly show where you need help;. Clearly show expected and actual results.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I call the following code in the loop,

NSArray *resultArray = [overAllResultArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"trip_detail != null"]];

`resultArray` return the not null objects only

Answer (score 0):

Use filter to loop over a collection and return an Array containing only those elements that match an include condition.